# ERROR Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v6

com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig" was not found in the UIManager.

When running an application on android i get this error. It builds correctly but crashes with exception. I have installed React-native-screens, @React-native/navigation and the dependencies listed on https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/